# TestCase fails with discover -s but running one-by-one shows OK

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

Have multiple files under `unit_tests` folder. Running `TestCase` separately shows tests succeed. If I run them with

```
python -m unittest discover -s unit_tests/*
```

raises errors. Looks like `test_*` methods are running in parallel.

What can be the reason for such behavior that running `TestCase`-based class shows all tests are fine and running all TestCases together fails.

**Status Update**

Found the issue. As I was using metaprogramming for my classes I didn't write custom `__del__` implementation to clear all objects relating to the class. Thus Python was saving references to the object and next time class instance was initialized it remembered previous instance values.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason and wrote status update.

My class was like:

```
class MyClass:

    items = []

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
```

When I was appending `obj` to MyClass and then removing instance with `obj` in `items` it remained there when was creating next instance.

```
class MyClass:

    items = []

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def __del__(self):
        [self.items.remove(order) for order in self.items]
```